# How to use random_score in yii2 elastic search when working with dataprovider

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

How can i add random_score in dataprovider search query?

I am using yii2-elastic search extension.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch

Comment: Pls explain in detail about your query .. Can u post some code which u hv tried ??

Comment: @vijaynathji   I have used elastic search dataprovider method. But i want to search data randomly. Elastic search have function like ["query" =>["function_score" => ['random_score' => ['seed' => 96582]]]], but how to use it with dataprovider.

Comment: Example Code:   $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => User::find(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ]
]);    https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-data-providers.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to set all fields in attributes() including the random_score field.

And then Try this way.

```
  $UserDetail = User::find();
    if($this->search != '') 
            {
                $query = $UserDetail->query($condition);
            }
            else
            {
                $query = $UserDetail;
            }

    $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => $UserDetail, 'pagination' => [ 'pageSize' => 10, ] ]);
    return $provider;
```